# All Iterations Fail for a Scenario Outline using Serenity with Cucumber-JVM

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd

I have setup a Scenario Outline using Cucumber-JVM and Serenity.  When I run one of my tests, one of the iterations fail; however, the other subsequent iterations of that scenario outline fail as well even though they should pass.

Simplified Sample of my Scenario Outline:

```
Scenario Outline: Validate Circuit Bandwidths

Given I am logged in to the page
When I select '<bandwidth>' for bandwidth
And I click validate
Then the circuit 'bandwidths' match the input

Examples: 
  | bandwidth |
  | DS0       |
  | DS1       |
  | DS3       |
```

Sample of page file that validates the code:

```
public void validateCircuitBandwidth(int id, String inputBandwidth) {
    WebElementFacade bandwidth = find(By.id("quoteControl_circuit-" + id + "_bandwidthDropDown"));

    String submittedData = "";
    if (inputBandwidth.equals("null"))
        submittedData = Serenity.sessionVariableCalled("bandwidth");
    else
        submittedData = inputBandwidth;

    String expected = submittedData.toUpperCase();
    String actual = bandwidth.getSelectedVisibleTextValue().toUpperCase();
    System.out.println("Circuit " + id + " | Expected: " + expected + " | Actual: " + actual);

    Assert.assertEquals("Circuit " + id + " Bandwidth does not match input",expected,actual);
}
```

What is supposed to happen is I'm also uploading an xml file for input.  Some of those fields are blank for bandwidth.  When they are blank, it is supposed to select from the entered bandwidth in the step shown above.  Code shown here is checking to see if the spot is blank (which end up being circuits 1,2,5,6).  If it is blank then check against the session variable set through Serenity.  What doesn't make sense is that the printed output for each circuit (as shown below) is showing the correct information; however, the same exact variables used in the assert method are acting as if they don't match even though they should be correct.

Output:

```
Circuit 0 | Expected: DS1 | Actual: DS1
Circuit 1 | Expected: DS0 | Actual: DS1
[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity -                                                          

TEST FAILED: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - TEST FAILED AT STEP Validate circuits bandwidth
[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - Circuit 1 Bandwidth does not match input expected:<DS[0]> but was:<DS[1]>
Circuit 0 | Expected: DS1 | Actual: DS1
Circuit 1 | Expected: DS1 | Actual: DS1
Circuit 2 | Expected: DS1 | Actual: DS1
Circuit 3 | Expected: OC3 | Actual: OC3
Circuit 4 | Expected: DS3 | Actual: DS3
Circuit 5 | Expected: DS1 | Actual: DS1
Circuit 6 | Expected: DS1 | Actual: DS1
Circuit 7 | Expected: OC12 | Actual: OC12
[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - 

TEST FAILED: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - TEST FAILED AT STEP Validate circuits bandwidth
[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - Circuit 1 Bandwidth does not match input expected:<DS[0]> but was:<DS[1]>
Circuit 0 | Expected: DS1 | Actual: DS1
Circuit 1 | Expected: DS3 | Actual: DS3
Circuit 2 | Expected: DS3 | Actual: DS3
Circuit 3 | Expected: OC3 | Actual: OC3
Circuit 4 | Expected: DS3 | Actual: DS3
Circuit 5 | Expected: DS3 | Actual: DS3
Circuit 6 | Expected: DS3 | Actual: DS3
Circuit 7 | Expected: OC12 | Actual: OC12
[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity -                                                         

TEST FAILED: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - TEST FAILED AT STEP Validate circuits bandwidth
[main] ERROR net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - Circuit 1 Bandwidth does not match input expected:<DS[0]> but was:<DS[1]>
```

Comment: Looking at your failing tests makes me belive that you actually have an applikation issue rather than a tooling issue. What happens if you disable all your assertions? Wil the execution pass? If so, look at your applikation rather than your tools.

Comment: Yes, the application is failing on the first test.  However, the other tests should pass (and they do if you don't run the first one for DS0).  That's where the problem lies.  These subsequent tests run after the first failed test should pass/fail correctly instead of failing also.

Comment: I also want to add that when I run something like DS1 before DS0, DS1 test case passes and then the DS0 still fails (like it should at the application's current state); however, the DS3 still fails when it shouldn't.  The tests that should pass only fail after they are run after the failed test (the DS0).  I should also point out this only happens in an isolated Scenario Outline.  If I run multiple scenario/scenario outlines, then they are not affected by the failed test in this particular scenario outline.